# Função js não roda no chrome, devido ao window.event

Tags: javascript

Li alguma coisa a respeito do srcElement e vi que quando eu faço window.event.srcElement, essa abordagem funciona apenas no IE. Bem, não tenho subsídios suficientes para discutir isso. O que passa é que uma função que eu tenho aqui, não funciona no chrome. Abaixo a função:

```
function MarcarCelula() {
    celula.selecionaCelulaViaTD(window.event.srcElement);
}
```

Vem dois erros:

> 1) Uncaught ReferenceError: celula is not defined
>
> 2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

A referência que eu peguei para afirmar minha hipótese acima foi nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209654/window-event-srcelement-doesnt-work-for-firefox/%22aqui%22) do SOen

Comment: Coloque o código todo se possível, pois o primeiro erro parece estar relacionado com o objeto `celula` e não com `window.event`.

Comment: Sim o srcElement ele está disponível apenas no IE, para todos brownser você pode usar o target  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o `window.event` e o `window.event.srcElement` são bem especificos do IE, neste caso você precisa realizar algumas verificações para tornar o script compativel com outros navegadores.

```js
var teste = document.getElementsByName("teste");

var onTesteChange = function (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  target = event.target || event.srcElement;  

  alert(target.id);
}

for (var indice in teste) {
  teste[indice].onchange = onTesteChange;
}
```

```html
<input id="teste1" name="teste" type="radio" />
<input id="teste2" name="teste" type="radio" />
<input id="teste3" name="teste" type="radio" />
```

No caso `target` recebe o `Element` que disparou o evento.